# Failed to install phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, phonegap-plugins, ionic3

I am following [Ionic Push setup](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#setup) guide but I am getting an error trying to install phonegap plugin:

> cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID=123456789 --save --verbose

Im getting and error:

> Error: Invalid Version: broken

this is `ionic info --verbose` generate following output:

```
[DEBUG] Loading global plugin @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy
[DEBUG] Throwing PLUGIN_NOT_INSTALLED for global @ionic/cli-plugin- proxy
[DEBUG] Loading local plugin @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova
[DEBUG] Loading local plugin @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular

global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.1.4
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : android broken
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 2.2.0

System:

Node       : v6.9.1
OS         : Windows 10
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 3.10.8
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link ::
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Try to install plugin using this command
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push